# Entity Framework 6 Db First connection string configuration in asp.net 5 MVC 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

I am currently trying to set an MVC6 application with Entity Framework 6 Db first. When it tries to access the db it says it can't find a Connection String.

The Context looks like this:

```
Partial Public Class MyEntityContext Inherits DbContext

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("name=MyEntities")
End Sub
```

The config.json looks like:

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "SiteTitle": "TestMVCApplication"
    },
    "Data": {
        "MyEntities": {
          "ConnectionString": "Server=*********;initial catalog=system.buysend.com;persist security info=True;user id=****;password=***********;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
        }
    },
    "EntityFramework": {
        "MyEntities": {
          "ConnectionString": "Server=**********;initial catalog=system.buysend.com;persist security info=True;user id=*****;password=**********;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
        }
    }
}
```

Does this look correct? Can using EF6 DB first be used with MVC6?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: your are using mvc6 in vb.net right

Comment: The class library that handles the EF is VB but the MVC6 application is in C#. We have managed to get the two referenced but the EF class library just can't see the connection string in the appsettings.json or the config.json

Comment: i dont know about vb. i show you how can i write in myself in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
IConfiguration configuration = new Configuration().AddJsonFile("config.json");
var connectionString = configuration["Data:MyEntities:ConnectionString"]);
```

Comment: I still get the error when doing that.
This is the Startup function in Startup.cs
 
`var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()`
                `.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")`
                `.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);`

            `builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();`
            `Configuration = builder.Build();`

            `var connectionString = Configuration["Data:BuySendEntities:ConnectionString"];`

Comment: While code-only answers are still answers, it would be better to add some explanation.